# getting error: "Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" while commiting the build code

Tags: angular

I have used the following command for making build file of my project :

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false.
```

the build file was made successfully, and added, but it upon committing the code, it threw error.

Comment: Try to include an actual question when posting to stack overflow read here -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. There's almost no information provided about what you're trying to do, and this makes it very difficult to help.  Maybe start with a clearer title to help others find your question